# Client Side Header Post Request possible?

Tags: post, curl, header, client-side

I made an http Header post request with curl, and i made it work.
But may Problem is that the Server IP is sent.
And with cURL it is impossible to sent the Client ip.

Is there another possibilitiy to do the request with another programming language to submit the client ip?

Comment: Sorry but this question is not making sense. What do you mean it sends the server IP? curl does HTTP over TCP, it will of course do a connection between a client and a server. Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Not completely.

But try adding IP headers , like
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR:12.12.12.12
REMOTE_ADDR:12.12.12.12

These may work on some case.